# formatting Datetime string

Tags: c#, datetime

i have the following object that can be nullable at times follows

```
public string issued {get;set;}
```

The `issued` string looks like this: `2022/02/29 22:00:00 +00:00`

I want to assign the issued variable to another variable as `2022/02/29` when its not null.

This is what i tried:

```
var item = new model() {
    issuedDate=issued.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "" : issued.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd")
}
```

But it throws an error:

> can not convert from string to system.IformatProvider?

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to parse it to a `DateTime` first `DateTime.Parse(issued).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")` also note you want upper case M for month where as lower case m is minute.  Note you might want to use `DateTime.TryParse` just in case it's not an actual date string.

Comment: One thing to remember: _there is NO SUCH THING as a "Datetime string"._ There are only Datetime values and string values. If you have a string and you want a Datetime, you parse the string to create the Datetime value. If you have a Datetime and you want a string, you must call ToString(). It's also generally better to get values into the Datetime format as soon as possible, and keep them that way as long as possible, and only convert back to string when absolutely necessary.

Comment: Or better yet, if you know the exact expected format, use `TryParseExact`.

Comment: @juharr thank you that worked. i just cant upvote your comment

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `DateTime` as helper with `TryParseExact` to determine if the source is a valid `DateTime` format. Via the `DateTime` helper variable you can then create any `DateTime` formatted strings you need to.

```
string   issued = @"2022/02/29 22:00:00 +00:00";
string   issuedDate;
DateTime dateTimeIssued;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(issued, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTimeIssued)) {
  issuedDate = dateTimeIssued.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
}
```

Be aware that `TryParseExact` only works if the format is known to the system culture.

Answer (score -1):

you can try for format;

```
 string.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}",issued);
```

this will be return **2022/02/29** for you

and you can look this page, for more information on DateTime format.

https://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: "this will be return 2022/02/29 for you" - it really won't. `issued` is a string variable.

Comment: im using this, all the time. Maybe he can try to.

Comment: If you're doing this *with a string* then you're doing it wrong. I suspect you're *actually* doing it with a `DateTime` value instead. Check the code where you're doing it (and ideally change it to `x.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")` instead, as a simpler and more efficient way of expressiong the same thing...)

Comment: If you don't believe me, try https://dotnetfiddle.net/PxfAtF for yourself. The output is "2022/02/29 22:00:00 +00:00" rather than "2022/02/29".